# How to ignore the outliers in a seaborn violin plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

See the violinplot:
[image]

here I'm showing the points to show that the long tail of the violin is due to a single point. I would like to ignore these outliers points so that I have a more concise violin plot. Can I do that with seaborn when plotting the violin or do I have to remove them from the distribution myself?

Comment: You have to remove them manually before passing the data for plotting. If we look into seaborn's [violin plot api](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html), there is no parameter specified for removing extreme outliers.

Comment: you can also change the y-axis upper limit to clip the tail without changing the data: `ax = sns.violinplot(…) ; ax.set_ylim(ymax=2)`

Comment: @JohanC I would personally clean up the data, just provided an alternative ;)

Comment: You'll need to manage the data in the dataframe and then plot.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by excluding the outlier data while passing it through the plot function.
e.g.

```
sns.violinplot(y = df[df["Column"]<x]["Column"])
```

wherein, `df` is your dataframe. `Column` is the name of the column you want to plot and `x` is the outlier value that you want to exclude.